# .Net Core Console App - Debug Fails - The connection with the remote endpoint was terminated

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

Debug-->Start Debugging fails with error "The connection with the Remote Endpoint was terminated".

Developed a very simple .Net Core Console Application with a small set of dependencies and < 100 lines of code. In fact Project.JSON is below.  It ran great on my machine.  When another developer Git-Cloned it and tried to debug it in VS 2015, they keep getting "Unable to start program... The connection with the remote endpoint was terminated".  I am at a loss because there should not be a "remote endpoint".  This is a local machine application.  This is not a web application and it is not set to run/connect to or debug on another machine, so what causes this error?

Project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Dapper": "1.50.0",
    "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess": "12.1.24160719",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    "ETimeLibrary": "1.0.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Net": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see you have an Oracle package and Dapper as reference. Could it be that they can't reach the database? A database is also a remote endpoint unless it's an InMemory Db.

Comment: Debugging will not even start.  Set breakpoint on first line.  Has not even reached a line of code that is trying to connect to a DB.  It gets DB connection string from AppSettings.json which has not even been loaded yet.

Comment: How does your startup/main method look like?

Comment: .NETCore generates 64-bit programs but VS is 32-bit.  That requires the remote debugger engine to bridge the gap, it uses "endpoints" to establish the process-interop mechanism.  This exception is a wonky-machine problem, anti-malware is always on top of the list.  Make an exclusion, disable it, try another machine.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant very helpful.  I wish there was a way to tell which software was the cause of this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I sincerely hope this saves someone a week's worth of aggravation in the future.  The issue ended up being the **Digital Guardian** software.  I never want to leave my own questions unanswered.

Now for some editorial comments: What a horrible software package!  Been doing Microsoft Stack development since VB 3.0 and never did I run into an issue with Visual Anything (Interdev, Studio, etc.) not working that was this hard to figure out.  Not only did it break debugging 64-bit applications (debugger works if you set your configuration and debug x86 or 32-bit), but it also slowed the machine down to a crawl.   Just say "no" to digital guardian.

Comment: What did you do to fix it? Did you remove Digital Guardian?

Comment: Initially yes, we had to remove Digital Guardian from all developers machines initially.  we have since resolved the issue with the vendor and a patched version of Digital Guardian now is allowing debugging to work.  However, that product still impacts performance of the workstation.  It's still not very pleasant to have on a machine, though it got a little better.

Answer (score 1):

Check that if the Remote Debugging on the Azure app is set to ON in the portal and has the correct Remote Visual Studio version.

[image]